# How do I print from a list from loop that is then passed into a formula in a loop?

Tags: python

The goal is:
Starting at the year 1900 count every year to input year.
Then run it through leap year formula.
Print only years that are leap years.

I can get the counter to work and print, I can get leap year formula to work, 1 year at a time. I would like to combine both. What am I doing incorrectly?

```py
counter = 1900

my_list = []

my_list = [str(item) for item in input("Enter ending year: ")]

while counter < my_list:

    counter += 1
    my_list.append(counter) # adds each value to list

if str(my_list) % 4 == 0 and str(my_list) % 100 != 0 or str(my_list) % 400 == 0: 
    print(str(my_list)[1:-1] + " is a leap year")
else:
    pass
```

Comment: I don't get your `my_list` code. When I input `1904`, I get `['1', '9', '0', '4']`. Also, when I try your code, I get a `TimeLimitError: Program exceeded run time limit.`

Comment: There's so much wrong here I don't know where to start. `for item in input(...)` sets `item` to each character in the input. So you're creating a list of the characters in the input. `counter < my_list` compares a number with a list. `str(my_list) % 4` makes no sense, `%` should be performed on numbers, not a string.

Comment: What is `while counter < my_list` supposed to do?

Comment: The code you posted does not work (doing things separately), so I suggest you fix it first.

Comment: You need to completely start over and think more carefully about each step in the process. It's so far off that I can't figure out how to fix it without just doing the whole assignment from scratch for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to be quite new to python and your code is not working I will just guess what you want to do and propose an answer

```py
begin = 1900
end_as_str = input("Enter ending year: ") # input returns a string
end_as_int = int(end_as_str) # therefore you have to cast it to an int

for year in range(begin, end_as_int): # to give it here to range
    if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0):
        print(str(year) + " is a leap year!")
```

Be aware that this will not include the end year
as `range(1,4)` for example would give you the numbers 1, 2 and 3 in an iterator, so the end is not included

I hope that you are a not submitting this right away to a teacher like this, and without going through it and understanding it, as I do not want to be the guy doing assignments for you. If it helps you to better understand python I am happy ;)

Edit: If you do not understand something from my solutin (for example `range`) try googling for it or search on youtube, you will likely find an explanation

Comment: You can take input as int in a single line too: `end_as_int = int(input("Enter ending year"))`

Comment: That is true, wanted to be explicit to make it easily understandable

Comment: Thank you for the solution, and information. And to answer your question, no this was not an assignment. This was something I thought of, to try and combine several of the assignments I have done. I am out of work, and trying to teach myself.  Thanks again